# Changing color of a specific reference using natbib

Tags: latex, bibtex, biblatex

Similar post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242042/how-to-change-text-color-a-particular-reference-in-the-bibliography-in-latex-u), but this is not exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a Latex article with some citation. Since last revision I've added new references, and I would like that the new references appears in red in my bibliography.

The idea that I had is to create a new command so I can have 2 citation commands, the classical \citep{} that I'm already using, and another one such as \citepred{} that will make the reference appears in red.

Here is a minimal working exemple :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%Import the natbib package and sets a bibliography  and citation styles
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}} %Citation-related commands

\title{Natbib Example}

\author{Overleaf team}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First Section}
This document is an example with two cited items: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite[see][chap 2]{latexcompanion} and Einstein's journal paper \citep{einstein} (that I would like now that the reference appears in red). 


%Imports the bibliography file "sample.bib"
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

and here is the sample.bib file :

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
 
@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

I have no idea how to create this new command to have the \citepred command.

I've tried using makeatletter and etoolbox to create a new command but nothing is working for now.

I could go in my bib text and write \color{red} before and after each new entry but this will be pretty long.

Thanks